# operand type clash:image is incompatible with xml

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

When I try to insert the dynamically created XML into a temp table its shows a error

> "operand type clash :image is incompatible with xml".

I already split the query when I execute the query and just select the XML its working. Only problem is that its not allow to insert into a table.

```
   "SET @sSQL1 = '
     SELECT  ' + @ColumnList + '
     FROM TB1 IPI WHERE  TBID= ' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) +' FOR XML RAW (''TB'') ,ROOT(''Table'') '

INSERT INTO @TBLTRANSXML(INCTRANSXML)           
EXEC (@sSQL1)"
```

Comment: For one thing, it means you've not been paying attention to a warning that Microsoft have been putting out for more than a decade: [ntext, text and image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187993.aspx): "**ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them"

Comment: Please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging, and let me know what you think of it. Ping me using `@halfer`, thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in that table there is no image or ntext or text field

Answer (score 0):

I got this

```
"SET @sSQL1 = 'select (
 SELECT  ' + @ColumnList + '
 FROM TB1 IPI WHERE  TBID= ' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) +' FOR XML RAW (''TB'') ,ROOT(''Table'')) '

INSERT INTO @TBLTRANSXML(INCTRANSXML)           
EXEC (@sSQL1)"
```

Adding a select in front will solve the problem.